# error importing functions and variables from other js files

Tags: javascript

i am having a server side rendered node-express-js project ..

i have a js file which contains an object , when i am trying to import that file in backend controller files by doing

`const _something = require(directory name)`

i am able to import it properly

but when i am trying to import the same file in my front-end assets files i am getting an error as following

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

on frontend js file i am importing it as :-
require {something} from '../../dir_name'

here is my export

```
PoStatus = {
    "Work Order Raised":"1",
    "Pending Request Approval":"2",
    "Pending Quotes":"3",
    "Quote Pending Approver":"4",
    "Pending Purchase Order":"5",
    "Purchase Order Raised":"6",
    "Purchase Order Closed":"7",
    "Work Order Closed":"8",
    "Rejected":"9",
    "Quote Pending Proc. Mgr.":"10"
  }

module.exports={PoStatus}
```

and my import is :-

```
import {PoStatus} from '../../../constants/poStatus'

function approveReturnRejectQuote(status) {
  $.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm!',
    content: `Are you sure you want to $
```

here is a snapshot of my directory

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIZQy.png

so i am exporting from constants/poStatus to assets/patra/js/quotesDetails
and i am getting a big fat error . however my IDE is giving suggestions regarding what object is imported and what key value pairs it holds but browser throws an error

Answer (score 0):

In nodeJs (js running on Desktop) to import and export you must use:

```js
require('here the path') 
module.exports = { /* variables to export */ }
```

And in Js (js running on browser)

```js
import 'here the path'
export { /*here variables*/}
```

if you want to use import in nodeJs you must config with webpack: https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/ to use moderJs (with import and export) then it will transform to oldJs

My recomendation:

- If you are building something simple use syntax from nodeJs
- If you build something more complex you must configure webpack